# How to get appdelegate to display a UIViewController instead of TableViewController

Tags: soql, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I have a **Salesforce Mobile SDK** app that presents the main view `planner.m` (after log in) as a TableView and I want to change this to a `ViewController` with a `TabBarController` and `NavigationBarController` with some items such as a table and textfield or maybe a collection view included then with the view.
I have inserted the code of the `appdelagate.m` and the `planner.m` below.
What parts of `appdelegate.m` do I need to modify to stop the app from presenting the TableView and replace it with the `UIViewController`? Below is the code from the a`ppdelegate.m`
Also, I renamed `RootViewController` to Planner.

```
________________________ 
 AppDelegate.m:
________________________

    /*
 Copyright (c) 2011, salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved.


 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "InitialViewController.h"
#import "Planner.h"
#import "SFAccountManager.h"
#import "SFAuthenticationManager.h"
#import "SFOAuthInfo.h"
#import "SFLogger.h"

// Fill these in when creating a new Connected Application on Force.com
static NSString * const RemoteAccessConsumerKey = @"3MVG9rFJvQRVOvk7XZ8r_ucvE0qFE1Iqa_pGNpegHQso9T0P9xqjl8Ou0LnLGvcl42STSqVZXUO9DV2l.n7lS";
static NSString * const OAuthRedirectURI        = @"mysampleapp://auth/success";

@interface AppDelegate ()

/**
 * Success block to call when authentication completes.
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy) SFOAuthFlowSuccessCallbackBlock initialLoginSuccessBlock;

/**
 * Failure block to calls if authentication fails.
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy) SFOAuthFlowFailureCallbackBlock initialLoginFailureBlock;

/**
 * Handles the notification from SFAuthenticationManager that a logout has been initiated.
 * @param notification The notification containing the details of the logout.
 */
- (void)logoutInitiated:(NSNotification *)notification;

/**
 * Handles the notification from SFAuthenticationManager that the login host has changed in
 * the Settings application for this app.
 * @param The notification whose userInfo dictionary contains:
 *        - kSFLoginHostChangedNotificationOriginalHostKey: The original host, prior to host change.
 *        - kSFLoginHostChangedNotificationUpdatedHostKey: The updated (new) login host.
 */
- (void)loginHostChanged:(NSNotification *)notification;

/**
 * Convenience method for setting up the main UIViewController and setting self.window's rootViewController
 * property accordingly.
 */
- (void)setupRootViewController;

/**
 * (Re-)sets the view state when the app first loads (or post-logout).
 */
- (void)initializeAppViewState;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize initialLoginSuccessBlock = _initialLoginSuccessBlock;
@synthesize initialLoginFailureBlock = _initialLoginFailureBlock;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [SFLogger setLogLevel:SFLogLevelDebug];

        // These SFAccountManager settings are the minimum required to identify the Connected App.
        [SFAccountManager setClientId:RemoteAccessConsumerKey];
        [SFAccountManager setRedirectUri:OAuthRedirectURI];
        [SFAccountManager setScopes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"api", nil]];

        // Logout and login host change handlers.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(logoutInitiated:) name:kSFUserLogoutNotification object:[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginHostChanged:) name:kSFLoginHostChangedNotification object:[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager]];

        // Blocks to execute once authentication has completed.  You could define these at the different boundaries where
        // authentication is initiated, if you have specific logic for each case.
        __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
        self.initialLoginSuccessBlock = ^(SFOAuthInfo *info) {
            [weakSelf setupRootViewController];
        };
        self.initialLoginFailureBlock = ^(SFOAuthInfo *info, NSError *error) {
            [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] logout];
        };
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kSFUserLogoutNotification object:[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kSFLoginHostChangedNotification object:[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager]];
}

#pragma mark - App delegate lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self initializeAppViewState];
    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:self.initialLoginSuccessBlock failure:self.initialLoginFailureBlock];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)initializeAppViewState
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //self.window.rootViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View.xib" bundle:nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)setupRootViewController
{
    Planner *rootVC = [[Planner alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = navVC;
}

- (void)logoutInitiated:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self log:SFLogLevelDebug msg:@"Logout notification received.  Resetting app."];
    [self initializeAppViewState];
    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:self.initialLoginSuccessBlock failure:self.initialLoginFailureBlock];
}

- (void)loginHostChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self log:SFLogLevelDebug msg:@"Login host changed notification received.  Resetting app."];
    [self initializeAppViewState];
    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:self.initialLoginSuccessBlock failure:self.initialLoginFailureBlock];
}

@end

____________________
Planner.m
/*
 Copyright (c) 2011, salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved.

 */


#import "Planner.h"

#import "SFRestAPI.h"
#import "SFRestRequest.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation Planner

@synthesize dataRows;

#pragma mark Misc

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.dataRows = nil;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"OutThere App";

    //Here we use a query that should work on either Force.com or Database.com
    //SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Visit_Date__c FROM Customer_Visits__r) FROM Account WHERE Visit_Date__r = YESTERDAY LIMIT 1000"];
    SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Nett_Sales__c, Price__c FROM Account WHERE Sales_Rep__c includes ('Mark Philips') AND Id IN (SELECT Customer__c FROM Customer_Visits__c WHERE Visit_Date__c > 2012-01-01)"];
    //@"SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Sales_Rep__c includes ('Mark Philips') AND Id IN (SELECT Customer__c FROM Customer_Visits__c WHERE Visit_Date__c > YESTERDAY)  ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 10000"
    [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark - SFRestAPIDelegate

- (void)request:(SFRestRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(id)jsonResponse {
    NSArray *records = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"records"];
    NSLog(@"request:didLoadResponse: #records: %d", records.count);
    self.dataRows = records;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)request:(SFRestRequest*)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"request:didFailLoadWithError: %@", error);
    //add your failed error handling here
}

- (void)requestDidCancelLoad:(SFRestRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"requestDidCancelLoad: %@", request);
    //add your failed error handling here
}

- (void)requestDidTimeout:(SFRestRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"requestDidTimeout: %@", request);
    //add your failed error handling here
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

//13-9-13-1030: Removed this becasue it seems to be covered already with the didSelectRowAIP method
//13-9-13-1030: - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)itemTableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//13-9-13-1030: {
//13-9-13-1030:     [itemTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
//13-9-13-1030: NSDictionary *obj = [self.dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//13-9-13-1030:     DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithName:[obj objectForKey:@"Name"] sobjectId:[obj objectForKey:@"Id"] quantity:[obj objectForKey:@"Quantity__c"] price:[obj objectForKey:@"Price__c"] county:[obj objectForKey:@"BillingCounty"] nett_rev: [obj objectForKey:@"Sales_Rev__c"] telephone:[obj objectForKey:@"Phone"]] ;
//13-9-13-1030: [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];

//13-9-13-1030: }
//Test to see if the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath gets around the issue of unable to select first time
//- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)itemTableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *)itemTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated: YES];
    //[itemTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NSDictionary *obj = [self.dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithName:[obj objectForKey:@"Name"] sobjectId:[obj objectForKey:@"Id"] quantity:[obj objectForKey:@"Quantity__c"] price:[obj objectForKey:@"Price__c"] county:[obj objectForKey:@"County__c"] nett_rev:[obj objectForKey:@"Sales_Rev__c"] telephone:[obj objectForKey:@"Phone"]];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataRows count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

   // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    //if you want to add an image to your cell, here's how
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = image;

    // Configure the cell to show the data.
    NSDictionary *obj = [dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =  [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[obj objectForKey: @"Sales_rev__c" ]];
    //this adds the arrow to the right hand side.
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you app there is a delegate method: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I found that it should be called very first as shown in you code. So you need to change here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Initialize your own window
    UIWindow *mywindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    self.window=mywindow;

    // Initialize your own viewcontroller 
    MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];

    // You said you want to use it with TabBarController So
    // Wrap you view controller
    UITabBarController *myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
    self.myTabBarController=myTabBarController;

    // makeThemVisible
    [self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //[self initializeAppViewState]; // You don't need it as every thing has been done here
// Login Status    
[[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:self.initialLoginSuccessBlock failure:self.initialLoginFailureBlock];

    return YES;
}
```

One more thing to use `UITabBar`(myTabBarController) you need to set property for it here (in `Appdelegate`).

Conclusion is wrap your `UIViewController` with `UITabaBarController`.

Comment: I updated my code in 'AppDeleagte.m', thank you for your help and I created a property at the head, but I get an error on the UITabBarController line: "No visible interface for 'UITabBarController' declares the selector 'initWithRootViewController.'"